# Can't get Cucumber to recognise tags

Tags: cucumber

I have a Cucumber feature file that begins:

```
@wip
Feature: Delete User
  As an administrator, I should be able to delete any user (including myself)
  provided at least one administrator account remains.
```

When I run it with `cucumber --tags @wip` I get:

```
Using the default profile...
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s
```

If I remove the `@wip` and run `cucumber` without the `--tags` parameter it correctly picks up all the scenarios for the feature.

I'm clearly missing something very simple -- what it is?

Comment: Can you check your cucumber.yml and see if --tags ~@wip is set in your default profile?

Comment: Ah, yes. I still have the default cucumber.yml (I hadn't even realised it was there), and that's buried in the ERB.

If you make this an answer rather than a comment I'll give you credit for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the default profile in the cucumber.yml file and remove `--tags ~@wip` which is causing the tag to be skipped.

Cheers